# Android Development - Command "adb devices" not listing my device

Tags: android, eclipse-adt

I see many people has this problem and so I see many solutions as well. But none is working.

I am having Ainol Novo8 Dream QuadCore Tablet running Android 4.1.1. My Window machine is Win 7 (with all updates).

For above I have download usb_driver i got from somewhere but window is not taking it. It says it is already up-to-date. Even after uninstalling the driver it does not take mine but update from net. My device is fully connected through USB without Yellow warning. 
**Do, I still need to use usb_driver I got from somewhere for my Tablet ?**

**I read about SDK setup, but I did not find it anywhere**. I have Eclipse with ADT from Google Developer page. 
Also, there were **no .... google/usb_drive/** folder exist. For info, Virtual Device is working correctly on my Eclipse setup.

I read about two files which looks important: **adb_usb.ini and  android_winusb.inf**. Both are not present in my installation. Though in the downloaded usb_driver for Ainol android_winusb.inf exist.

**Tried with "adb start-servers" and adb kill-servers"**. No help for "adb devices".

My folder structure is 
C:\Eclipse_N_ADT\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130522\sdk

I have done with USB Debug Mode on. Notification is showing this. I removed the slide password thinking if it can interfere with. My device is rooted by default. 
My device is not coming on Portable Device list. When I check through Devices and Printer on Win7 then I can see window has found device drivers. There it shows my Tablet Model under driver list.

Comment: what does it say when you do adb start-server in command prompt

Comment: The `extras/google/usb_driver` folder will not show up unless you download that package through the Android SDK Manager. You'll need to tick the second item from the bottom [depicted here](http://www.tech-recipes.com/wp-content/uploads/AndroidSDK-9-SDK-Manager.png). To be honest, it doesn't really sound like a driver issue though.

Comment: @MH That extra/Google usb driver is already installed. Yesterday, I got tired working on usb_driver thing.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of anyone else still struggling with this, I found a driver package that works.

I recently purchased an Ainol Novo Hero 10 II for development purposes and faced the same problem as you.  This solution works for me:

Source:
http://www.slatedroid.com/topic/70585-adb-drivers/

1. If you have already installed any previous drivers but your ADB doesn't recognise it, go to your Device Mangers to uninstall and remove all existing drivers associated with your new device.
2. Download modified USB driver from here: http://yadi.sk/d/54lX5c2O386XU
3. This driver is UNSIGNED so install at your own risk (although it seems to work for me).  Windows has a Driver Signature Enforcement that you need to disable.  A google search will lead you to instructions (sorry not enough rep points to post more than 2 links :P)
4. Reinstall with the new driver.  The package already includes an adb_usb.ini file that includes a Vendor ID 0x10d6 that should help recognise your device.
5. Reboot Windows (and remember to reactivate your Drive Signature Enforcement) and it should be working.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps for recognize your device with 'adb devices' command.
For this your device should be enabled 'USB Debugging' option in {developer options}.

1. Click 'Start' button on computer.
2. Right click on Computer.
3. Select 'Manager' > 'Computer Management' window will be opened.
4. Click on 'Device Manager'
5. Now Expand 'Portable Devices' > Here you can find your device name with yellow exclamation symbol.
6. Right click on your device Name.
7. Select 'Update drivers Software'
8. Select second option 'Browse my computer for driver software'.
9. Select 'Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer'.
10. Common hardware types list will be opened.
11. Select 'Android Device' > click on 'Next' button.
12. Now select 'Android ADB Interface' and Click 'Next' button.
13. it pops up 'driver warning' > Click 'Yes'.
14. Now you will see the 'Windows has successfully updated your driver software'.
15. Now you can see the pop up in your device with 'digital signature' > click 'OK'
16. Now open cmd and write command 'adb devices' > now you can see the your device is listed with some ID.

Answer (score 0):

Quick guide:
Connect your device with Android Debugging enabled to your PC

Open Device Manager

Your device should appear under 'Other devices' listed as something like 'Android Phone' or similar.

Right click that and click on 'Update Driver Software...'

Select 'Browse my computer for driver software'

Select 'Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer'

Double-click 'Show all devices'

Press the 'Have disk' button

Navigate to [wherever your SDK has been installed]\extras\google\usb_driver

Select 'Android ADB Interface' from the list of device types.

Press the 'Yes' button

Press the 'Install' button

Press the 'Close' button